# Fill list of start/end dates with dates in between

Tags: python, datetime

Given a list with the following structure :

```
[start_date_cycle1, end_date_cycle1, start_date_cycle2, end_date_cycle2, ..., end_date_cycleK]
```

where all elements are timestamps, I would like to get the following

```
[[start_date_cycle1, start_date_cycle1 +1d, start_date_cycle1 +2d, ..., end_date_cycle1],
[start_date_cycle2, start_date_cycle2 +1d ...]]
```

So if the input is `['10-23-2019', '10-26-2019' , '11-02-2019', '11-06-2019']`, the output would be :

```
[['10-23-2019', '10-24-2019','10-25-2019', '10-26-2019'] ,
 ['11-02-2019', '11-03-2019','11-04-2019','11-05-2019','11-06-2019']]
```

P.S : The length of the list will always be an even number (so no start of cycle without end).

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `timedelta` from `datetime` module to iterate from start to end date, as below

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt, timedelta as td
strp,strf,fmt=dt.strptime,dt.strftime,"%m-%d-%Y"

a=['10-23-2019', '10-26-2019' , '11-02-2019', '11-06-2019']

print([[strf(k,fmt) for k in (strp(i,fmt)+td(days=n) for n in range((strp(j,fmt)-strp(i,fmt)).days+1))] for i,j in zip(a[::2],a[1::2])])
```

**Output**

```
[['10-23-2019', '10-24-2019', '10-25-2019', '10-26-2019'], ['11-02-2019', '11-03-2019', '11-04-2019', '11-05-2019', '11-06-2019']]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using `datetime` module

**Ex:**

```
import datetime

data = ['10-23-2019', '10-26-2019' , '11-02-2019', '11-06-2019']
result = []
for s, e in zip(data[::2], data[1::2]):          # (10-23-2019, 10-26-2019)....
    s = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%m-%d-%Y")
    e = datetime.datetime.strptime(e, "%m-%d-%Y")
    temp = []
    while s <= e:
        temp.append(s.strftime("%m-%d-%Y"))
        s += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    if temp:
        result.append(temp)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[['10-23-2019', '10-24-2019', '10-25-2019', '10-26-2019'],
 ['11-02-2019', '11-03-2019', '11-04-2019', '11-05-2019', '11-06-2019']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the strings as `datetime` objects, use them to do the necessary calculations (by adding `timedelta` objects), and then convert back to strings at the end.

To produce the output as a nested list, as specified in the question, the temporary variable `dates_out` is used to generate the inner lists, which are appended to the main list (`out`) inside the loop.

If you want to use day-month-year ordering, change the `'%m-%d-%Y'` to `'%d-%m-%Y'` in the one place where it occurs.

```
import datetime

dates = ['10-23-2019', '10-26-2019' , '11-02-2019', '11-06-2019']
format = '%m-%d-%Y'

dts = [datetime.datetime.strptime(date, format) for date in dates]

out = []
i = iter(dts)
for start, end in zip(i, i):
    dt = start
    dates_out = []
    while dt <= end:
        dates_out.append(datetime.datetime.strftime(dt, format))
        dt += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    out.append(dates_out)

print(out)
```

This gives:

```
[['10-23-2019', '10-24-2019', '10-25-2019', '10-26-2019'],
 ['11-02-2019', '11-03-2019', '11-04-2019', '11-05-2019', '11-06-2019']]
```

(newline inserted for readability)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily using `dateutil` module. You can install it by doing `pip install python-dateutil`.

`map(parse, lst)` would convert the dates from string to datetime obj; `zip(*[map(parse, lst)]*2)` would create pairs of datetime objs, so that you can navigate them as `(start,end)` pairs. And finally `rrule(freq=DAILY, dtstart=start, until=end)` creates a range of datetime objs from start to end

```
>>> from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> 
>>> lst = ['10-23-2019', '10-26-2019' , '11-02-2019', '11-06-2019']
>>> res = [[dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y') for dt in rrule(freq=DAILY, dtstart=start, until=end)] for start,end in  zip(*[map(parse, lst)]*2)]
>>> 
>>> print(res)
[['10-23-2019', '10-24-2019', '10-25-2019', '10-26-2019'],
 ['11-02-2019', '11-03-2019', '11-04-2019', '11-05-2019', '11-06-2019']]
```